# how to validate dropdownlist inside repeater in asp net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu, repeater

I am having dropdownlist inside repeater.

It is not always visible. It is visible only on certain condition is true.
On button click  I have to validate that dropdownlist on only if it is visible.

I have to achieve this on client side if it is possible.

Can anyone help me for this.

Comment: Just add a required field validator? Enable/disable when you set the ddl visible.

Comment: CAN WE USE required field validator inside repeator

Comment: yes you can.  Of course, I'm guessing you've probably tried it by now...

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to perform validation for dropdown.

Give some class name to dropdownlist if its visible.
On button click find dropdownlist using class name and perform validation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#buttonId").click(function(){

var _value=$(".dropdownclassname").val();

if(_value=="condition")
{
$(".dropdownclassname").css("border", "1px solid red");
return false;
}


});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

As per clarification in the comments, you can add a required field validator in your repeater - this should work as expected.

If needs be, you can enable/disable it as required.